# Click on specific button with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Python, Selenium, XPath.

I want to open this page https://www.tesla.com/en_gb/models/design#battery and click the performance button programmatically with python.

Here is what I want to click on:
[image showing what I want to click on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMWrM.png)

My problem is properly describing the button. Maybe I don't understand xpath properly or there's a better method to point to the desired element.

Here's what I tried

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('../Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('https://www.tesla.com/en_gb/models/design#battery')
A = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/main/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]')
A.click();
```

and I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\666.py", line 4, in <module>
A = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/main/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]')
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/main/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]"}
(Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)
```

full xpath {/html/body/div/div/main/div/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMWrM.png)/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMWrM.png)}

html of element i want to click on

```
<div role="button" tabindex="0" class="group--options_block m3-animate--all" aria-label="Performance"><div class="group--options_block_title"><span><p class="group--options_block--name text-loader--content" tabindex="-1">Performance</p></span><p class="group--options_block-container_price text-loader--content price-not-included">£95,800</p></div></div>
```

im copying and pasting the full xpath of the element i want. is that not the correct way to do this?

edit:
if it works the range should be 367 not 379

Answer (score 1):

Use following xpath

```
//div[@class='group--options_block_title']/span/p
```

OR

```
//p[contains(text(),'Performance')]
```

OR CSS selector

```
div[aria-label='Performance']
```

Don't forget to introduce `Implicit` or `Explicit` wait to avoid synchronization issue in your scripts. [reference](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Comment: this didnt return an error, but i didnt see the effect i expected of it clicking on the performance button

Comment: just my old one but with the new xpaths you suggested. none actually made the page be on performance mode.

Comment: I tried this and its absolutely working fine at my end `A = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Performance')]")
A.click()`

Comment: are you closing the browser in script just after click ?

Comment: are you sure its actually clicking on performance. does range read 367 or 379

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code sometime sites are taking too long while loading so would be great if you use WebDriverWait in your solution. Also its not good practice to use Abs XPath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://www.tesla.com/en_gb/models/design#battery')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(text(),'Performance')]")))
print element.text
element.click()
element1 = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(),'367')]")))
print element1.text
```

Output: 
[image]

Comment: this doesnt work. if it clicked on performance it would print 367mi. not 379

Comment: please find updated solution. its working fine now. Also kindly hit upvote button and accept answer once you verify it from your end